# Attempting to automate a schedule and still display data to upper management

Tags: google-sheets-api

My boss likes the lay out of the existing sheets, but one of my goals is to run analytics and use time metrics to access performance. I know I need to be able to reference the data in the cells but currently I'm inputting 3 sets of data into one cell. Start date, Finished date, and Paid Date which all correspond to a schedule item at the top of my column. Is there a way to put a cell within a cell to keep track of three sets of data under one column that I can reference individually?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnGhJ.png)

Is there a way to put a cell within a cell to keep track of three sets of data under one column that I can reference individually? My boss would like for me to keep it as close to this format as possible to make it easier to review the data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.